# Flex item not aligning self with styled-components in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox, styled-components

I expected the div inside MatchReport to align to the center of the screen. But nothing happens when I change align-self nothing happens. I just need to get it to the center of the screen, I'm new to using FlexBox, please help

THANKS

**JSX**

```
...
return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <MatchReport ref={report} className="report">
                <div>
                    <h1>{renderChamp()}</h1>
                    {renderWinnerImg()}
                    <p className="match-report" ref={matchReportRef}>
                        hello world
                    </p>
                    <button className="reset-from-report-btn" onClick={resetFromReport}>
                        New Battle
                    </button>
                </div>
            </MatchReport>
...
```

**STYLED-COMPONENTS CSS**

```
export const MatchReport = styled.div`
    text-align: center;
    /* MUST BE CHANGED */
    display: flex;
    /* display: none; */
    /*  */

    div {
        background: white;
        display: inline-flex;
        align-self: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px 10px #aaaaaa;
        z-index: 500;
        padding: 1.3rem;
        height: auto;
        width: 75%;
        text-align: center;
        /* must change */
        /* opacity: 0; */
        transition: 2s;

        ${mobile} {
            position: relative;
            width: 90%;
            height: 600%;
        }
    }

`;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fill the container of the nested `div`.

And ensure to use align/justify according to your needs.

Your example:

```
export const MatchReport = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  // fill the container with any values
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;

  div {
    height: auto;
    width: 75%;
  }
`;
```

Generic example:

```
const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  div {
    width: 500px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: palevioletred;
  }
`;

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <div />
    </Container>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit priceless-fast-wpiwc]

Comment: Thank you very very very much Dennis